# Using CUTE for C++ tests in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing

I read online that I should take my existing project, which is in a development stage, build a shared library out of it, and use this library for testing. What I am planning to do is move all my current work into a new shared library eclipse project, use this for testing on the go, and also go on developing in this new shared library project, which I will use for both testing and developing. However, when I hit build for the shared library project, so that I see if changes I've made there compile at all, I get

Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "libMatchingEngineLibrary.so"  ./src/Fill.o ./src/GlobalMatchingEngine.o ./src/Main.o ./src/Order.o ./src/OrderBook.o ./src/SingleFifoMatchingEngine.o ./src/SingleMatchingEngine.o
/usr/bin/ld: ./src/Fill.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `vtable for Fill' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./src/Fill.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libMatchingEngineLibrary.so] Error 1

Why can I not even build this shared library project, let alone be able to start testing it?
What am I doing wrong? Should I be able to build it? Is it Ok if I do development in this kind of shared library project(which I want to do only for the convenience of doing testing and development in parallel)?

Edit: The Fill class mentioned in the error is alphabetically the first class in the project. I am building by hitting the hammer icon on eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

That error says exactly what you're missing. Recompile with the `-fPIC` flag. That will allow "Position Independent Code", which you should probably understand before attempting to make shared object libraries. Good luck!

Comment: How do I do this in eclipse? I am not compiling from terminal, just building inside the IDE.

Comment: I've never used eclipse, but I would imagine you go to something like project properties and look for something like "additional compiler flags"